# copying back *.ibd files in mariadb

Tags: mariadb, database-restore

I have full MariaDB backup with this lost files with mariabackup --backup
They just removed by stored procedures from current instance.

How can I restored this file (history_log#P#p201712030000.ibd) back? I have ibdata1 backuped also.

1. Stop MariaDB
2. Copy *.idb files
3. Start MariaDB

This didn't work. 
What should I do more?

Comment: MySQL uses DISCARD TABLESPACE for that, given similarities between MariaDB and MySQL, you could look it up.

Comment: Copying just ibd files is unsafe because there is other information about the table in ibdata1.